# How to sort data in map reduce hadoop?

Tags: sorting, hadoop, mapreduce

I am working with a programme that has 4 MapReduce steps.the output of my first step is:

```
id      value
 1        20
 2         3
 3         9
 4        36
```

I have about 1,000,000 IDs and in the second step i must sort the values.the output of this step:

```
 id      value
 4        36
 1        20
 3         9
 2         3
```

How can I sort my data in map reduce? Do I need to use terasort? If yes, how do I use terasort in second step of my programme? 
Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by 4 mapreduce steps? You are running Map Step and Reduce step 4 times ? If you are writing a MapReduce program then you have control over Map Step and Reduce step.

Comment: @prashantsunkari no,i have 4 steps and in each of them there is a map and a reduce function. each step does different work.the second step must sort the output of first step.

Comment: one of the biggest advantage of mapreduce is it sorts your data according to your key. You want to sort according to what?

Comment: @smttsp according to the values.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort according to `value's`, make it `key in map` function. i.e.

```
id      value
1        20
2         3
3         9
4        36
5         3
```

(value)  (key) in map function

```
output will be 

key      value
3         5
3         2
9         3
20        1
36        4

map<value, id> output key/value  
reduce <value, id>
```

if you want id to be in the first column, this will work.

context.write(value, key);

Note that, id's are not going to be sorted