# Sort in mapreduce

Tags: java, sorting, hadoop, mapreduce

I am learning hadoop mapreducing. I am trying to sort (by value) using mapreduce. Below is my code for the mapper:

```
static String splitChar = "\t";
static int colIndexone = 0;
static int colIndextwo = 1;

public static class MapClass extends MapReduceBase implements
    Mapper<Object, Text, IntWritable, Text> {
public void map(Object key, Text value,
        OutputCollector<IntWritable, Text> collector, Reporter arg3)
        throws IOException {
    int number;
    String word = "empty";
    String row = value.toString();
    String colVals[] = row.split(splitChar);        
    word = colVals[colIndexone].toString();
    number = Integer.parseInt(colVals[colIndextwo]);

    collector.collect(new IntWritable(number), new Text(word));
}

}
```

Here I am reversing the  pair so that, in the reducer I can sort based on the values. I followed [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16402383/how-to-sort-data-in-map-reduce-hadoop).

Now, can anyone help me how to approach for the reducer code!

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE :**

I wrote this as reducer

```
public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements
    Reducer<IntWritable, Text, IntWritable, Text> {
public void reduce(IntWritable key, Iterator<Text> values,
        OutputCollector<IntWritable, Text> arg2, Reporter arg3)
        throws IOException {
}
}
```

But how to get the sorted values?

Comment: It is just the identity reducer, that's it.

Comment: Can you explain your requirement with example because I didn't get what you are trying to do in the given code. Every time you are emitting 999 as your key.why?

Comment: Forget  about 999. My requirement is to sort a key value type column by it's value using mapreduce. Please check out the link in the question. I developed the map.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut...I updated my question with the reducer. How to print the sorted key, value pair now?

Answer (score -1):

**Solved:**

Below code is added to the reducer

```
while(values.hasNext()){
        arg2.collect(key, (Text) values.next());
    }
```

Comment: Instead of doing that, just skip the `job.setReducerClass()` command, and it will do the same thing. it will call the IdentityReducer, by default, as Thomas said in his comment...